# MariaDB sum sizes from id in table to id's in another

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sum, mariadb

I'm a total novice at SQL queries, so hopefully it's okay to ask this question here. In my MariaDB I have two tables that look like this:

```
downloads
(`uid`, `tstamp`, `fid`, `notes`) VALUES
(1, 1352001731, 14, ''),
(1, 1357403888, 20, ''),
(2, 1357432414, 9,  ''),
(2, 1357544813, 4,  ''),
(1, 1357653803, 12, '');

files
(`id`, `guid`, `uid`, `size`) VALUES
(12, 35, 57, 10910074),
(20, 47, 42, 9348993),
(11, 35, 57, 76510074),
(47, 47, 52, 45548993),
(9,  35, 37, 1560074),
(4,  47, 22, 6788993),
(15, 51, 12, 323450993);
```

I would like to query a particular `uid` in the `downloads` table and sum the sizes of the `id`'s matched in `files` with the corresponding `fid`'s in `downloads`. So for example, if I queried `uid` 2 then it should return the sum of sizes from `id` 9 and 4 in `files` (8349067). Any tips or advice is appreciated.

My complete schema is here:

https://pastebin.com/Bb96ZWMw

SOLUTION: a slight change to the accepted answered helped me to get the result I wanted:

```
SELECT SUM(size)
FROM   downloads d
JOIN   files f ON d.fid = f.id
WHERE  d.uid = 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd join the two tables and sum the sizes:

```
SELECT   d.uid, SUM(size)
FROM     downloads d
JOIN     files f ON d.fid = f.id
GROUP BY d.uid
```

If you're just interested in a particular `uid`, you could have that in the `where` clause, and forgo the grouping:

```
SELECT SUM(size)
FROM   downloads d
JOIN   files f ON d.fid = f.id
WHERE  d.uid = ...
```

Comment: I had to make a minor change to your example and it works! I needed to include `d` prefix for the table. thank you for showing me the way.